# VB formatting numbers

Tags: vb.net

Stupid formatting issue.  When I run this, instead of getting a numeric grade, I just get zeros for score 1, score 2 and average.  Otherwise it works perfectly.  Exam week and my brain is too tired to keep playing with it.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
Option Strict On
Public Class frmStudent
Dim students As Student()


Private Sub addButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles addButton.Click
    Dim thisStudent As New Student(IDTextBox.Text, nameTextBox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(score1TextBox.Text), Convert.ToInt32(score2TextBox.Text))

    ReDim Preserve students(Student.Count - 1)
    students(Student.Count - 1) = thisStudent

    IDTextBox.Text = ""
    nameTextBox.Text = ""
    score1TextBox.Text = ""
    score2TextBox.Text = ""

End Sub

Private Sub displayButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles displayButton.Click
    Dim fmtStr As String = "{0,-10}{1,10}{2,10}{3, 10}{4,10}"
    Dim form As New frmDisplay()
    Dim average As Double


    form.lstDisplay.Items.Clear()
    form.lstDisplay.Items.Add("There are " & Student.Count & " students.")
    form.lstDisplay.Items.Add(String.Format(fmtStr, "ID", "Name", "Score1", "Score2", "Avg Score"))

    For Each studentObj As Student In students
        form.lstDisplay.Items.Add(String.Format(fmtStr, studentObj.ID, studentObj.Name, studentObj.Score1, studentObj.Score2, average))
    Next
    form.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: What does the `Student` class look like?

Comment: Show the code where you are setting the values of score1 and score2. Have you stepped through the code to make sure the values are what you'd expect in those properties?

Comment: I can't see where you're calculating the value for `average` ;)

Comment: Thank you, I found it in the rest of the code.  I was setting the values of the grades backwards. ie: score1 = score1value when it should have been score1value = score1.

Comment: When you feel tired like that, give it a good night sleep, see if still a problem next morning. This approach is very common in software development.